# Splitting string on multi-character delimeter

Tags: c#, .net

```
string Idstr="ID03I010102010210AEMPD4677EID03I020102020208L8159734ID03I030102030210IPS1406974PT03T010109981815938030202PT03T0201109899488666030201PT03T0301109818159381030203PT03T040112919818159381030201";

string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "ID03I0" };
string[] result;

result = IdStr.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**This is the result:**

```
result[0]=10102010210AEMPD4677E
result[1]=20102020208L8159734
result[3]=30102030210IPS1406974PT03T010109981815938030202PT03T0201109899488666030201PT03T0301109818159381030203PT03T040112919818159381030201
```

**Desired result:**

```
result[0]=ID03I010102010210AEMPD4677E
result[1]=ID03I020102020208L8159734
result[3]=ID03I030102030210IPS1406974PT03T010109981815938030202PT03T0201109899488666030201PT03T0301109818159381030203PT03T040112919818159381030201
```

As you can see I want to include delimiter **ID03I0** to the elements.

NOTE: I know I can include it by hardcoding it. But that's not the way I want to do it.

Comment: You could always just append the delimiter to the beginning of all elements....

Comment: Its your data.  Include whatever you want in it.

Comment: why not simply adding it to the start of every result-element?

Comment: I can include it by hardcoding it. But thats not the way I want to do it.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521146/c-sharp-split-string-but-keep-split-chars-separators

Comment: You don't have to hard-code the value if that's what you mean...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = IdStr.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => stringSeparators[0] + x).ToArray();
```

This adds the seperator to the beginning at every element within your array.

EDIT: Unfortunately with this approach you are limited to use just one single delimiter. So if you want to add more you´d use Regex instead.

Comment: This is the best approach. There is also the regex one but this should be a lot easier on CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Following Regex pattern should work.

```
string input = "ID03I010102010210AEMPD4677EID03I020102020208L8159734ID03I030102030210IPS1406974PT03T010109981815938030202PT03T0201109899488666030201PT03T0301109818159381030203PT03T040112919818159381030201";  
string delimiter = "ID03I0";//Modify it as you need
string pattern = string.Format("(?<=.)(?={0})", delimiter);
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/6oT4yk)

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/521172/2530848).