# Splitting a string using regex: *category**bob*!cookshop

Tags: c#, regex

This is what I have been trying so far. Basically, I want to split the string but **keep** the separator. My regex knowledge is very limited but I've been trying using a forward lookup to match the expression. Whenever I try to introduce `\*1` into the string split, it goes badly so I'm not sure what to do and if this is possible.

```
var tests = new List<string> 
{
    "*foo**bar*!bob",
    "*foo*!42",
    "!foo*bar*"
};

foreach (var expression in tests)
{
    var strings = Regex.Split(expression, @"(?=[!])");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, strings));
}
```

1st line:

```
*foo**bar*
!bob
```

2nd Line (this is working as expected)

```
*foo*
!42
```

3rd line

```
{EMPTY LINE}
!foo*bar*
```

But I'm *trying* to get back is:

1st line

```
*foo*
*bar*
!bob
```

2nd line - As Above (this is correct)

3rd line

```
!foo
*bar*
```

Comment: Just fixed my example - It wasn't in line with my requirements listed.

Comment: Try lookbehind instead? http://stackoverflow.com/a/521172/1180926

Comment: The problem with a look behind is the char I need to keep ends up on the wrong line and from my tests, I still can't get the results I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
var tests = new List<string> 
{
    "*foo**bar*!bob",
    "*foo*!42",
    "!foo*bar*"
};

foreach (var expression in tests)
{
    var strings = Regex.Split(expression, @"(?=[!])|(\*[^\*]+\*)").Where(exp => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(exp));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, strings));
}
```

Results:

```
*foo*
*bar*
!bob
*foo*
!42
!foo
*bar*
```

Comment: Legend! Thanks very much, works perfectly. I wasn't too far off in my second test locally so I'll take some satisfaction in that ;) I'll mark it as the answer when I'm allow. Thanks again for your time.