# Split the string into substrings with saving big spaces

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a `string` filled something like this -

```
".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. ."
```

I need to *split* it to *substrings*, but a **space in the middle** must be written to string array too.

```
public static string Decode(string morseCode)
{  
    string[] words = morseCode.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

    ...
}
```

I expect :

```
words[0] = "...."; 
words[1] = "."; 
words[2] = "-.--"; 
words[3] = " ";     // <- Space in the middle should be preserved
words[4] = ".---";
...
```

Comment: You probably have fixed width data and have to split on column index instead of splitting on spaces, or you have tab delimited data and have to split on the tab instead of a space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string with delimiters but keep the delimiters in the result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680128/split-a-string-with-delimiters-but-keep-the-delimiters-in-the-result-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @OwenPauling that doesn't seem like a real duplicate. OP here does not want to keep all the delimiters. Only the one that has both meanings: as a delimiter and as a symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions* in order to *match* required chunks:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static string Decode(string morseCode) {
  string[] words = Regex.Matches(morseCode, @"(?<=^|\s).+?(?=$|\s)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) 
       ? match.Value 
       : match.Value.Trim())
    .ToArray();

  //Relevant code here
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string morseCode = ".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .";

  string[] words = Regex.Matches(morseCode, @"(?<=^|\s).+?(?=$|\s)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) 
       ? match.Value 
       : match.Value.Trim())
    .ToArray();

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words
    .Select((word, i) => $"words[{i}] = \"{word}\""));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
words[0] = "...."
words[1] = "."
words[2] = "-.--"
words[3] = " "
words[4] = ".---"
words[5] = "..-"
words[6] = "-.."
words[7] = "."
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! 
I have an error: The name 'match' does not exist in the current context. How i understand, i need to initialize it, how should i do it correctly?

Comment: @Roomey: I'm sorry for the typo; it should be lambda `.Select(match => match.Value...` (please, see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try below also. It is with Regex itself.

```
string code = ".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .";
    code = Regex.Replace(code, @"(\s{2})", " ").ToString();
    string[] codes = code.Split(' ');
    for (int i=0; i<codes.Length;i++){
    Console.WriteLine(i + " - "+codes[i]);
    }
```

The output is as below

```
0 - ....
1 - .
2 - -.--
3 - 
4 - .---
5 - ..-
6 - -..
7 - .
```

I just replaced all consecutive spaces (>=2) with one space and than `split` the string. Hope this will help.

Comment: Your idea a bit generalized: `code = Regex.Replace(code, @"\s{2,}", m => new string(' ', m.Value.Length == 2 ? 1 : 2));` (if we have 2 spaces we treat them as 1, if 2+ spaces - as 2)