# C# - How to keep the delimiters of Regex.Split in all resulting substrings?

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to use Regex.Split to split on a delimiter, and also have that delimiter split onto all substrings.

For Example:
I have a string `"holidays/*/2024"`, and separator `'*'` and I want to have following: `"holidays/*","*/2024"`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com) thread shows how to split and keep the separators as their own elements of the result. I have also been able to use Lookbehind `(?<=[*])` and Lookahead `(?=[*])` separately, each achieving half of the desired result. I am struggling to see how to use both (or alternative solutions) to accomplish the desired result in a single expression.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string with delimiters but keep the delimiters in the result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680128/split-a-string-with-delimiters-but-keep-the-delimiters-in-the-result-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @gunr2171 The thread you linked shows how to add delimiters as separate substrings within the result set. I am hoping to have the delimiters be attached at the end and beginning of all substrings resulting from a split.

Comment: Regex does not work like this, you can have overlapping matches, but it cannot go forward and then backward, it always proceeds from left to right.

Comment: Try : string[] result = rgx.Split(input); string newStr = string.Join("*"",""*", result);

Comment: Not sure if you have to use split, but you might use 2 capture groups, and then check if the group values exist `([^/]+/\*(?=/))|(?<=(\*/[^/]+(?=/|$)))` https://regex101.com/r/IBAq7S/1\

Comment: Are there multiple delimiters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know C#, but a simple loop should be enough:

```cs
string[] splitted = text.Split(delimiter);

for (var i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++) {
    var fragment = splitted[i];

    if (i > 0) {
        fragment = delimiter + fragment;
    }

    if (i < splitted.Length - 1) {
        fragment += delimiter;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(fragment);
}
```

Try it [on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PlPAXN).

Comment: Yes, seeing as how complex a RegEx solution to this problem is, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

To split a string using Regex.

```
    using System;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string input = "holidays/*/2024";
            string pattern = @"(?<=\*)|\*(?=/)";
    
            string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
            foreach (string substring in substrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(substring);
            }
        }
    }

    Output

    holidays/
    /2024
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is imperative for my use-case that the delimiter persist on both resulting substrings. Expected result: [ holidays/* , */2024 ].

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use this horrible-looking regex:

```
Regex re = new Regex(
  @"
    (?:^|\*)        # Match and capture either the beginning of string or '*',
    (?=             # then
      ([^*]+)       # a group 1+ non-'*' characters, followed by
      (\*|$)        # another group of '*' or the end of string.
    )
  ",
  RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
);
```

...then `.Join()` the groups in each match to get the final result:

```cs
MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(text);

foreach (Match match in matches) {
  Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join("", (
      from Group matchGroup in match.Groups
      where matchGroup.ToString() != ""
      select matchGroup.ToString()
    ))
  );
}
```

Try it [on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W5tth9).